# Is Angularjs UI-ROUTER now statble?

Tags: angularjs

I am contemplating using the angularjs UI-Router or the ngRoute directive. 
from [this page here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) it says

"Warning: UI-Router is pre-beta and under active development. As such, while this library is well-tested, the API is subject to change. Using it in a project that requires guaranteed stability is not recommended."

My question is if this warning still stands of today or is the ui-router now ready for projects that require a guaranteed stability? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the official github page of ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), where all the development and other activity is, you see that the current release version is 2.10, while the site you linked to mentions 2.8, so changes have been made since the webpage you linked was made/updated.

Also, we can see this on the github page I linked to

> **Note**: UI-Router is under active development. As such, while this
>   library is well-tested, the API may change. Consider using it in
>   production applications only if you're comfortable following a
>   changelog and updating your usage accordingly.

This basically replaces the former warning.

---

*My question is if this warning still stands of today..*

So no, the warning doesn't still stand.

*..or is the ui-router now ready for projects that require a guaranteed stability?*

Sort of, if you follow the changelog and update your usage accordingly, as the note says, you should be fine.

Comment: @user3728830 if the question is answered, please accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's an old article (it's also using angular `1.1.5` - all of the `1.1.x`'s were unstable, and eventually became a stable version at `1.2`).

> Note: AngularJS versions 1.1.x are considered "experimental" with
>   breaking changes between minor releases. **Version 1.2 is the result of
>   several versions on the 1.1 branch, and has a stable API.** If you have
>   an application on 1.1 and want to migrate it to 1.2, everything in the
>   guide below should still apply, but you may want to consult the
>   changelog as well.

You can see information on all this here:

**[angularJS 1.0 to 1.2 migration](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngroute-has-been-moved-into-its-own-module)**

> **ngRoute has been moved into its own module** Just like ngResource,
>   ngRoute is now its own module.
>
> Applications that use $route, ngView, and/or $routeParams will now
>   need to load an angular-route.js file and have their application's
>   module dependency on the ngRoute module.